# Concatenate setting_ with an address

Tags: c

I have some trouble with concatenating setting_ with an address, which is then used to map to a struct type:

I use:

```
#define ADDR_TO_SETTING(ADDR) { #ADDR, setting_ ## ADDR}
```

Then I have a struct and an enum:

```
typedef struct
{
    uint8_t setting_ADDR_LOG_ACTIVE;
} settings_t

typedef enum
{
   ADDR_LOG_ACTIVE=0
} addr_e
```

Which is used as follows:

```
settings_t settings;

settings.ADDR_TO_SETTING(ADDR_LOG_ACTIVE) = false;
```

I always get a compiler error in the header, where the define is: "expected identifier or '(' before '{' token". What I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

With your macro

```
#define ADDR_TO_SETTING(ADDR) { #ADDR, setting_ ## ADDR}
```

the line

```
settings.ADDR_TO_SETTING(ADDR_LOG_ACTIVE) = false;
```

expands to

```
settings.{ "ADDR_LOG_ACTIVE", setting_ADDR_LOG_ACTIVE} = false;
```

which is a syntax error (particularly the `.{` part).

What did you expect to happen?

Comment: Oh, ye you are right, I tought this is the syntax for concatenation, but #define ADDR_TO_SETTING(ADDR) setting_ ## ADDR works just fine